# Resize icon prop of TabBar.Item

Tags: react-native

I have an icon required within TabBarIOS.Item. The size of the icon is 128 x 128. I want to resize it to 40 x 40. How can I do it?

```
<TabBarIOS.Item
  title="Place"
  icon={require('./assets/pin.png')}
>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to change the actual size of the image you can't do it in react native code. If you want to change the size you change the xcode project and add objective-c code to do this. You can have a look at this [link](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/663).